# Access Multiple PDF Files with Django Rest Framework and REACT frontend

Tags: django, file, django-rest-framework, backend

I am trying to access the uploaded files from my `Django-rest-Framework` which I uploaded with my `React Frontend`.

CourseDocument:

```
class CourseDocument(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='')
    document = models.FileField(upload_to='courses')
    course = models.ForeignKey(to='Course', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

To my DRF endpoint:

```
@action(methods=\['GET', 'POST'\], detail=True, url_path='documents', permission_classes=EMPLOYEE_PERMISSION)
def course_documents(self, request, \*args, \*\*kwargs):
    
    if request.method == 'GET':
        qs = CourseDocument.objects.filter(course_id=kwargs['pk'])
        fs = FileSystemStorage()
        filename = qs.first().document.path
        if fs.exists(filename):
            with fs.open(filename) as pdf:
                response = HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
                response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="mypdf.pdf"'
                return response
        else:
            print("NOT FOUND")
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = CourseDocumentSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(data=serializer.data, status=200)
        else:
            return Response(data=serializer.errors, status=400)
    
    return Response(status=200)
```

I tried it so far with the FileSystemStorage to send it in an HTTP Response with content type application/pdf.

This did work, but only for one single PDF File.

I want to avoid to pass the pdf as a link to my backend because of security reasons.

How can I achieve sending multiple pdf files to my frontend?

Comment: Am i right that you want to be able to download multiple pdfs? I dont think thats possible

Comment: Yeah right, @saro - I found a solution and I will provide it, when im ready.